# Prove that $\mathbb{P}[(\limsup A_n)-A_n]\rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

**Problem:** This is a problem from Problems in Probability by Shiryaev (Problem 2.1.16). It is worded as following: Let $A^*=\limsup A_n$. Prove that $\mathbb{P}(A^* -A_n)\rightarrow 0$

**Attempt:** I tried rewriting the expression in different forms. But none of them works. I think the following observation is crucial: let $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be defined as $x_n=\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_k)$. Then we know $x_n$ converges to limit $x:=\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n)$. So for sufficiently large $n$, we have that $x-x_N=\mathbb{P}([\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n]\backslash[\bigcup_{n=1}^{N}A_n])<\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is arbitrary.

Comment: Are the $A_n$ arbitrary events? If so, this is not true; let the probability space be $[0,1]$. Let $A_n=[0,\frac12]$ when $n$ is odd, and $A_n=[\frac12,1]$ when $n$ is even. Then $\limsup A_n=[0,1]$, so $P[ (\limsup A_n)-A_n]\to \frac12$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest ummm....I totally agree with this counterexample. Maybe  it should be added to the original problem that $A_n$'s are different for each $n$

Comment: Beware the correct problem is stated below : see the answer by Gabriel Romon.

Answer (score 1):

There has probably been a mixup in the English translation of the book. In the Russian edition the problem is (correctly) stated as

> Prove that $P(A_n\setminus \limsup_k A_k)\xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{} 0$ and $P((\liminf_k A_k)\setminus A_n)\xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{} 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space. Let $(A_{n})_n$
be a sequence in $\mathcal{F}$. Define $A=\limsup_{n}A_{n}:=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}\cup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_{k}$.
We go to prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(A_{n}\setminus A)=0$.

Proof: For each $n$, let $B_{n}=\cup_{k\geq n}A_{k}$. Then $(B_{n}\cap A^{c})_n$
is a decreasing sequence and $\cap_{n}(B_{n}\cap A^{c})=(\cap_{n}B_{n})\cap A^{c}=A\cap A^{c}=\emptyset$.
By continuity of finite measure, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(B_{n}\cap A^{c})=P(\cap_{n}(B_{n}\cap A^{c}))=0$.
Finally, observe that $A_{n}\cap A^{c}\subseteq B_{n}\cap A^{c}$.
It follows that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(A_{n}\cap A^{c})=0$.

Comment: Nice proof ! Note for self : the (corrected) statement of the problem is no more true if the measure is not supposed to be finite, take $A_n = B_n \cap A$ for disjoints $B_n$ whose measure is not vanishing (the latter implies the measure is not finite).